# Steam In Home Streaming from Ubuntu to macOS over VPN

Tags: linux, osx, windows, vpn, steam

in my office I have an **Ubuntu workstation with a decent gaming GPU**. At home, I have only a **13" MacBook Pro** which is not that much a gaming machine.

Fortunately, Steam has this great feature called **In Home Streaming**, where you can stream games from one machine to another. But unfortunately, both have to be **in the same network**.

Since the gaming machine in my office is behind **a firewall** and does **not have a public IP** (I could get one, but I do not want because of security reasons), we have a **VPN** installed on a gateway to access our business network using **IPFire**. As we do not need layer 2 information over VPN, we **do not have a bridged** `tap` device but a `tun` device, which **only does the layer 3** routing.

Now, the Internet **is full** of tutorials how to use Steam In Home streaming over a VPN connection. But: since **Steam uses UDP broadcasts** for service discovery and our **VPN and the office network are different subnets**, this does obviously not work because of our VPN setup.

At this point I decided to use **[ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com)**, which can be configured as a **layer 2 VPN** (virtual layer 1 in ZeroTier terminology).

**Now the strange things begin:**

The Linux workstation and the MacBook Pro **do see each other** over the ZeroTier network and **I can ping each other**. But they **do not see each other on Steam**. A workmate told me, he got it **working using a Windows** machine. So I borrowed a Windows device, installed Steam and ZeroTier and **it worked**. I could see the Linux workstation and the MacBook.

**So, here is my guess**: the discovery process for macOS and Linux is broken. In the **Steam logs** I could see, that they are listening on `0.0.0.0`, but I could not see on **which interface** they are sending the broadcast packets. I assume that they are sending the packets **on the default interface**, which is not the `zt0` interface set up by ZeroTier. But on Windows it seems to work and after the *nix machine sees the Windows computer, they are able to set up the connection between them.

My question is now **if you have any idea** how I can fix this problem. I've somewhat run out if ideas. I would be grateful for any help.

P.S.: If this is the wrong stackexchange site, please let me know. I will then repost this question on the appropriate page.

---

**Update:**

**My assumption was true.** I had a look into Wireshark and could clearly see, that **Steam uses the first non-loopback interface**. I guess a **redirection of the Steam ports** could solve the problem. What do you think?

Comment: actually, steam uses the first interface it finds with a default route.  this is why if i restart the steam client on my linux desktop (which also handles the pppoe adsl interface) it won't see the steam client on my win7 steam "games console" until I restart steam on that too.  I could fix that by running steam in docker or something but it's not important enough to overcome my laziness :)

Comment: btw, does your employer and/or their IT staff know what you're doing?  you've just punched a hole through their firewall so you can play some games on their desktop machine.   this is sometimes spelled "sackable offence".  and unless you have a very fast connection at home and at the office, performance will be awful anyway.

Comment: Everybody knows what I'm doing. In fact, my employer is curious if I can get it working. We are pretty free. We are just 10 employees and managing our infrastructure by our own. And I think I know what I'm doing so far :)

Comment: ok, that's cool.  just making sure that this wasn't a case of not realising that a new desktop gaming pc costs a lot less than having to find a new job.

Comment: so yeah, the iface discovery process is broken.  and there's no way to tell the steam client to listen on a specific interface.  IIRC there's a bug report in one of the steam discussion or support forums about it.  I'm pretty sure I posted one about that some time ago.  i didn't get the impression that it was a high (or even low) priority for valve.

Comment: if you were less lazy than I, you could google 'running steam client on docker` and then actually implement it.  I've done the googling bit, but haven't bothered with the implementation side of it.  i know that there are several steam docker images to choose from.  dunno if any work on docker on mac, or only docker on linux & X.